# postgres query optimization when always false where condition is present

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance

We have a query which goes like this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_a.userid       AS userId,
                table_a.screenname   AS screenName,
FROM   table_a
       LEFT JOIN table_b
              ON ( table_a.userid = table_b.userid )
WHERE  ( table_b.organizationid IS NULL )
       AND ( table_a.companyid = '20002' )
       AND ( table_a.defaultuser = 'f' )
       AND ( ( Lower(table_a.firstname) LIKE '%7189%'
               AND '%7189%' IS NOT NULL )
              OR ( Lower(table_a.middlename) LIKE '%7189%'
                   AND '%7189%' IS NOT NULL )
              OR ( Lower(table_a.lastname) LIKE '%7189%'
                   AND '%7189%' IS NOT NULL )
              OR ( Lower(table_a.screenname) LIKE '%7189%'
                   AND '%7189%' IS NOT NULL )
              OR ( Lower(table_a.emailaddress) LIKE '%7189%'
                   AND '%7189%' IS NOT NULL ) )
       AND ( table_a.status = '0' )
```

table_b.organizationid has a not NULL constraint so table_b.organizationid IS NOT NULL is equivalent to 1 = 2, but still postgres executes remaining part of the query, creates temporary table and returns zero rows after 15 seconds.

Without changing query, is it possible to improve performance of this query.
DB version is 9.1, but 9.3 also has the same behavior.

Postgres version: PostgreSQL 9.1.14 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3, 64-bit

table_a has 2.3 million rows
table_b has 5.4 million rows

table_a has 40 columns (too many to list here)
table_b has 2 columns

```
     Column     |  Type  | Modifiers
----------------+--------+-----------
 userid         | bigint | not null
 organizationid | bigint | not null
Indexes:
    "table_b_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (userid, organizationid)
    "ix_7ef4ec0e" btree (organizationid)
    "ix_fb646ca6" btree (userid)
```

Explain Plan

```
HashAggregate  (cost=638937.42..638937.43 rows=1 width=72) (actual time=21386.436..21386.436 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=443599.10..638937.40 rows=1 width=72) (actual time=21386.433..21386.433 rows=0 loops=1)
         Hash Cond: (table_b.userid = table_a.userid)
         Filter: (table_b.organizationid IS NULL)
         ->  Seq Scan on table_b  (cost=0.00..95488.04 rows=6020704 width=16) (actual time=0.009..4158.880 rows=5497919 loops=1)
         ->  Hash  (cost=441059.52..441059.52 rows=104846 width=72) (actual time=12356.795..12356.795 rows=215 loops=1)
               Buckets: 16384  Batches: 2  Memory Usage: 12kB
               ->  Seq Scan on table_a  (cost=0.00..441059.52 rows=104846 width=72) (actual time=43.250..12355.735 rows=215 loops=1)
                     Filter: ((NOT defaultuser) AND (companyid = 20002::bigint) AND (status = 0) AND ((lower((firstname)::text) ~~ '%7189%'::text) OR (lower((middlename)::text) ~~ '%7189%'::text) OR (lower((lastname)::text) ~~ '%7189%'::text) OR (lower((screenname)::text) ~~ '%7189%'::text) OR (lower((emailaddress)::text) ~~ '%7189%'::text)))
 Total runtime: 21386.608 ms
(10 rows)
```

-- Sameer

Comment: Have you tried creating a partial index? Something like `CREATE INDEX ON table_b (organizationid) WHERE organizationid IS NULL`. It should be a pretty small index, but it might help the planner.

Comment: @Sameer Naik try to create a view and then query the view .It will be much easier for you. It will reduce the time of query , You can query very fast.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info then [edit] your question and add the missing information

Comment: @jmelesky organizationid column has not null constraint, so index on it where organizationid IS NULL will have zero entries. Do you think it will still help?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Edited question as per your suggestion.

Comment: "*so table_b.organizationid IS NOT NULL is equivalent to 1 = 2*" no, it's not equivalent to 1=2 because of the outer join you are using. You are selecting rows from table_a that do not have a match in table_b. You could try doing that with a `not exists` condition. Sometimes that is faster

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Good catch! I missed the LEFT JOIN part. So that's the answer I was looking for. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @SameerNaik Please update the question with your answer so other know it's been solved.

Answer (score 0):

I know you don't want to rewrite the query. But query rewriting helps the planner a lot. I would write this query as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_a.userid       AS userId,
                table_a.screenname   AS screenName,
FROM   table_a
LEFT JOIN
(select userid from --i think only userid is needed in this query
   table_b  table_b.organizationid IS NULL ) as table_b
              ON ( table_a.userid = table_b.userid )
WHERE  
       ( table_a.companyid = '20002' )
       AND ( table_a.defaultuser = 'f' )
       AND ( ( Lower(table_a.firstname) LIKE '%7189%'
               AND '%7189%' IS NOT NULL )
              OR ( Lower(table_a.middlename) LIKE '%7189%'
                   AND '%7189%' IS NOT NULL )
              OR ( Lower(table_a.lastname) LIKE '%7189%'
                   AND '%7189%' IS NOT NULL )
              OR ( Lower(table_a.screenname) LIKE '%7189%'
                   AND '%7189%' IS NOT NULL )
              OR ( Lower(table_a.emailaddress) LIKE '%7189%'
                   AND '%7189%' IS NOT NULL ) )
       AND ( table_a.status = '0' )
```